# PDO inserting 1 instead of value from foreach statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a form that posts a bunch of data to this script that will insert into a db:

the posts are:

```
$_POST['fName'] = "bob";
$_POST['lName'] = "Jones";
$_POST['smsNum'] = "12345";
$_POST['pass1'] = "1234567890";
$_POST['company'] = "acme";
$_POST['uName'] = "bjones";
$_POST['perms'] = "user";
$_POST['active'] = "1";
```

my insert statement:

```
$ins = "INSERT into login (firstName,lastName,SMSNumber,password,company,userName,permissions,active) VALUES (:fName,:lName,:smsNum,:pass1,:company,:uName,:perms,:active)";
```

if i do this:

```
$stmt->bindParam(':fName',$_POST['fName']);
$stmt->bindParam(':lName',$_POST['lName']);
$stmt->bindParam(':smsNum',$_POST['smsNum']);
$stmt->bindParam(':pass1',$_POST['pass1']);
$stmt->bindParam(':company',$_POST['company']);
$stmt->bindParam(':uName',$_POST['uName']);
$stmt->bindParam(':perms',$_POST['perms']);
$stmt->bindParam(':active',$_POST['active']);
```

it works fine.

if I do this:

```
foreach($_POST as $k => $v)
{
    $stmt->bindParam(":".$k,$v);
}
```

the result is the digit "1" inserted into every field in db.  any thoughts why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `bindParam()` your are declaring that PDO should use the variable `$v` for all parameter. So when the statement is executed it will use the value from the last iteration of the foreach loop.

You have to do one of these:

```
$stmt->bindParam(":".$k,$_POST[$k]);
```

This will tell PDO to use the value from the `$_POST` variable.

Or:

```
$stmt->bindValue(":".$k,$v);
```

This will use the actual value in `$v` at the current iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

`bindParam` actually create an internal linkage between the variable you specify, and the matching placeholder in your query. Since you're doing:

```
foreach($_POST as $k => $v)
```

you're actually binding your placeholder to the `$v` variable, **NOT** the value that's in the query.

The variable's value is NOT access as part of the binding - you're just establishing a linkage. Only when you actually EXECUTE the query will the bound varaible's value be fetched.

When your foreach finishes, `$v`'s final value will be the `1` from `$_POST['active']`. And since you've bound that **SAME** `$v` to every placeholder in your query, you are inserting `1` everywhere in that new record.

Try:

```
foreach(array_keys($_POST) as $key) {
   $dbc->bindParam(":{$key}", $_POST[$key]);
}
```

instead, so you're binding to the matching $_POST entry.